# JQuery interfering with lxml parsing

Tags: jquery, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a website which was probably written poorly, so when you initially perform a GET request on their page, it responds with 5 entries in a mixture of html, javascript, jquery because it's the visual part of the page, and if you want to get more entries, you click a button, which internally performs a POST request on the same page along with the "pagination value" which is like the page you want, like if you want entries 6 to 10, you give a value of "2" to pagination value and if you want entries 11 to 15, you give a value of "3", and it does this asynchronously and appends the data to the end of the previous result set.

Sending/receiving is not a problem, in fact, when I try to scrape the page using lxml, I can easily get values for the first 5 entries, however, when I have to get the second set of data, I provide pagination value of "2" and I expect xml data back, because xml/html would be easy to parse, but here's my problem:

They return a weird combination of jquery AND html. It goes something like this:

```
$(".entry:last").after("
    <div class="entry">
    <p>some data</p>
    </div>
    <!-- 4 more entries omitted -->
");
```

When you inspect their website, this works flawlessly, the last 5 entries that just got downloaded asynchronously via AJAX, gets added sequentially to the first 5 entries, I looked into the "after" method of Jquery and I can confirm that it just appends the 5 entries after the 5th element.

When I initially scraped their data, the root element was a html tag, so I could parse it using lxml, but the response that they provide the moment I have to parse the result of this pagination is this weird mix of Jquery and html.

Also I can assure you that there is only one "after" method, and everything else is html, so basically 2 lines of Jquery, the first line and the last line, so I assumed I would just blindly remove the first and last line and then parse it again, but the response object that I get from the requests library, which I use to perform the POST operation, returns it as one long line of data, so I cannot do any readLine() on it, to seperate the first line from the second line from the last line, it's all just one line to me. So I would like pointers on how I would solve something like this.

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, the question is "How do I extract HTML embedded in javascript code".

The quick and dirty solution is to use a regular expression to extract the HTML. This is going to be a little finicky because of quoting but it's not too bad, you need a regular expression which can match a string with escaped quotes, this one will do the trick for doublequotes, it will match anything between doublequotes which is not a double quote, or is a quoted double quote:

```
"((?:[^"]+|\\")+)"
```

You can then use that to create a regular expression which will extract the contents of the html string from it's jquery wrapping:

```
import re

mixed_js_html = r'$(".entry:last").after("<div class=\"entry\"><p>some data</p></div>");')

m = re.search(r'after\("((?:[^"]+|\\")+)"\)', mixed_js_html):
html_code = m.group(1)
html_code = html_code.replace('\\"', '"') # unescape quotes
print(html_code)
# <div class="entry"><p>some data</p></div>
```

Comment: I don't know much about RE, but it's a good place to start, thank you :)